# How do I stop a job before its dependencies?

Tags: server, shutdown, upstart

I have a job that does some things and uses other locally installed services (such as the mail server).

Sometimes I do an ACPI shutdown but I need this service to complete the ongoing operation before actually shutting down the machine.

To make my job terminate gracefully I've configured upstart to send the appropriate signal and to wait for 2 minutes before using SIGKILL.

However that does not solve my problem because apparently the mail server also stops, but does so before my service, so eventually I don't get the result that I wanted.

How should I configure upstart to inform it of the existing dependency and so have it wait for my service to terminate before going on and terminate the other ones?

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make sure one Upstart job stops before another Upstart job stops?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/421923/how-can-i-make-sure-one-upstart-job-stops-before-another-upstart-job-stops)